# Why does my shell script not work in a docker container?

Tags: docker, shell, sh

I have written a very simple shell script ("test.sh") and put it into a container. I can see it using "> ls" in the Docker terminal. and its contents using "> more"  However, when I type "> ./test.sh" I get

```
/bin/sh: ./test.sh: not found
```

Here is the output for ls -l (I am operating as "user")

```
-rwxrwxrwx    1 user     group          327 Mar 24 14:14 test.sh
```

What am I doing wrong?

Additional information. Here is a minimal example:

```
#!/bin/sh
var=$1
echo $var
```

The solution is to add "sh" in front of the command

```
sh test.sh testMessage
```

gives back

```
testMessage
```

Additional note: Thanks to @David Maze.

I changed

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Comment: What produced this script; do you have a [mcve]?  What is the "shebang" line, the very first line of the file?  Is there any chance the script was produced on a Windows system and so has DOS-style CR+LF line endings (and the extra carriage return would be read as part of the interpreter name)?

Comment: @David Maze Thank you for your help. I am not certain why it worked outside of the container before but the same solution works inside and out. just add "sh" in front of the command.

Comment: What image are you actually running it in?  Does that image actually have GNU bash (Alpine images will not, for example)?  Your script doesn't seem to use any bash-specific syntax; if explicitly specifying `sh` as an interpreter works, can you change the shebang line to `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: @David Maze Thank you for the information. I had not paid attention the command I was using. Your answer expanded the systems where my code works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add "sh" in front of the command

```
sh test.sh testMessage
```

gives back

```
testMessage
```